# Arduino HTTP Post request

Tags: arduino-mega, http, ethernet-shield

I have a Arduino Mega with Wiznet 5100 Ethernet shield. Am trying to post some data onto localhost for started later on which will be accepted by a website. 
But when I try to post the data I get some error. When I try to send the same data via postman it gets accepted . But when it goes from arduino error occurs.
The arduino Code is as follows:

```
client.println("POST /api/trackers/5a28eddaf57a6e2060e85601/solars/5a3bb2adf57a6e1a71ca135b/arduino_data HTTP/1.0");

client.println("Host: 192.168.6.16");

client.println("Accept: application/vnd.mirasol.v1");
Serial.println("After Accept application vnd");

client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
Serial.println("After User Agent Arduino");

client.println("Accept: application/json");
Serial.println("After Accept application json");

client.println("Content-Length: ");
Serial.println("After content length");

client.println(postdata.length());

client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
Serial.println("After content type application json");

client.println("Connection: close");
Serial.println("After connection close");

client.println();
Serial.println("After client println");

client.println(postdata);
Serial.println("After post data");
Serial.println(postdata);
```

The output in the serial monitor is as follows:

```
    connecting...
connected
After Accept application vnd
After User Agent Arduino
After Accept application json
After content length
After content type application json
After connection close
After client println
After post data
{"current":10.50, "voltage":10.50}
H
disconnecting.
```

And the error shown in localhost is as follows:

```
2017-12-27 15:21:57 +0530: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
```

I have the application in Ruby on Rails with Mongoid as the DB.

FYI: New to coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem most likely stems from this bit:

```
client.println("Content-Length: ");
Serial.println("After content length");

client.println(postdata.length());
```

You have an extraneous "ln" in there causing the post data length to be on a separate line from the Content-Length:

```
Content-Length:
23
```

You should change the first `println` to a `print`. Also the order could do with changing to keep things logically grouped:

```
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.println(postdata.length());

Serial.println("After content length");
```

Which would result in:

```
Content-Length: 23
```

Comment: Well did that and the rails server responded... But now am getting Completed 204 No Content . I want to send the data from the body instead of the URL to keep the security good in a way.

Comment: I would suggest, for debugging, duplicate all client prints to the serial so you can see precisely what is being sent to the server.

Comment: That 204 was there since I had not given any view or response for when the request would come in... Just went into the function and added a json response to it and it worked like a charm ... Kudos to u for helping ...